# std::map::insert exception

Tags: c++, stl

This is another, "My code isn't working and i don't know why, " question i'm afraid. I just don't have enough knowledge of the stl to know why std::map::insert would throw an exception. If you know what cases it throws an exception, you can probably skip this wall of text and just answer. If you just desperately need some background on the issue, then have at it. I'll post my code and explain what is done, and i would be very grateful if all you with a better knowledge of the stl could explain what could be wrong with my call to insert.

I wrote an object awhile ago that i use occasionally as my go to factory object. It's main purpose is basically to take a string and store both the string and a "create new object function" pointer, so that in the end, you can call a function, pass a string, and if there is a valid registration for it, it returns a new instance of a derived object. Less talk, more code, here's what i got:

factory.h

```
#ifndef FACTORY_H
#define FACTORY_H

// library tools
#include <map>
#include <string>

// Simplified registration macros
#define DECLARE_DERIVED(T, base)    static Factory<base>::DerivedRegister<T> reg;
#define DEFINE_DERIVED(T, base, s)  Factory<base>::DerivedRegister<T> T::reg(s); 

template<class base>
class Factory
{
protected:
    template<class T>
    static base * createT() { return new T;}

public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, base*(*)()> map_type;

    virtual ~Factory(){ }

    static base * createInstance(const std::string & s)
    {
        if(!m_Map.count(s))
            return nullptr;
        std::map<std::string, base*(*)()>::iterator it = m_Map.find(s);
        return it->second();
    }

    template <class T>
    struct DerivedRegister;

protected:
    static map_type m_Map; 
};

template<class base>
template<class T>
struct Factory<base>::DerivedRegister : public Factory<base>
{
    DerivedRegister(std::string const & s)
    {
        m_Map.insert(std::pair<std::string, base*(*)()>(s, &createT<T>));
    }
};


#endif
```

here's a better explanation of what it does real quick. Let's say you have a base class, class A . and then you have any number of derived classes. I make a factory object somewhere templated to A, and then either create a derived register object manually, or use the macro at the top within the derived classes declaration to create a static registry object. Then you define it in the implementation and call it's constructor, passing in a string to be used to identify the object. using the factory member createInstance you can pass in a string identifier and have a derived object returned, pointed to by an A *.

example:

A.h

```
class A
{

};
```

A.cpp

```
// the map for this factory template has to be defined somewhere, as it is static
Factory<A>::map_type Factory<A>::m_Map;
```

b.h

```
#include <A.h>
class B : public A
{
  // anywhere in declaration of derived B
  DECLARE_DERIVED(A, B)
};
```

b.cpp

```
 // just somewhere in cpp file
 DEFINE_DERIVED(A, B, "B")
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  A * ptr;
  Factory<A> factory;

  ptr = factory.createInstance("B");
}
```

This object has worked for me in the past, mostly without a hitch. Now i'm doing a project a little more complicated. I've taken a liking to the data organization/ api design involved with game engines, and i'm just trying to implement a solution of cataloging, (but not instantiated) shaders, so that you have a whole list of the shaders you've programmed, but they will not be instantiated at run-time unless needed. That aside, this question actually has nothing to do with d3d11, or at least i hope not.

So here is what's going on. I have an object that represents a graphics-shader abstract class. All the shaders you wish to write must derive from this object. The you derive from and implement it's functions differently for all your different shaders.

let's call the base object "SYNC::D3D11Shader" in namespace sync and the derived shaders "ColorShader" "LightShader" and "TextureShader". Since i do not simply want to make an std::map of instances of these shaders within the rendering object, i make a factory within the rendering object like this.

D3D11Renderer.h

```
class D3D11Renderer
{
    // many other members...
    Factory<D3D11Shader> m_ShaderFactory;
    // many other member...
};
```

D3D11Renderer.cpp

```
// define this templated classes map or you'll get undefined errors
Factory<SYNC::D3D11Shader>::map_type Factory<SYNC::D3D11Shader>::m_Map;
```

and then in the ColorShader i use the macros like so

D3D11ColorShader.h

```
class D3D11ColorShader : public SYNC::D3D11Shader
{
  // ...lotsa members
  DECLARE_DERIVED(D3D11ColorShader, SYNC::D3D11Shader)
  // lotsa member...
};
```

D3D11ColorShader.cpp

```
// define the registery object with it's key here
DEFINE_DERIVED(D3D11ColorShader, SYNC::D3D11Shader, "ColorShader")
```

this all compiles fine, and where it throws it's exception is where i first call the registryObjects constructor in D3D11ColorShader.cpp, spefically at the insert call. the exception error is this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x772315de in Syncopate.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000004.

So in reality, the question boils down to, when does std::map::insert throw an exception and why. I just knew everyone would be asking for some background on what i'm doing. Low and behold, a giant wall of text has appeared! All i really need is a hunch.

also should i or should i not tag d3d11, because the question doesn't really pertain to it?

Comment: I didn't read the whole post, but Access violation usually means dereferencing a null pointer

Comment: @shengy - yup, but the thing is, the std::map within the factory is not a pointer. I never create a new map or delete it :\ . so when would it produce an exception with map not being a pointer? it would throw a compilation error if it wasn't defined :\ .

Comment: It does not throw an exception. There is no `throw` executed anywhere in the code, either yours or the library. The runtime system (the OS, for all practical purposes) wants to tell your program that it's borken, and this has the form of an exception. You have a bad pointer (data corruption) somewhere, and this results in an access violation in a place that may or may not be near the point of corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i have actually been laboring over this error for about a day, and only now do i realize what is wrong.

problem 1:

the derived shaders header was never actually included anywhere throughout the project, and despite the fact that it never needs to be directly instantiated, it still has to be included somewhere so it can be linked and included in build.

problem 2:

interesting enough, just like combinatorial said, the initialization order was not done one after the other, but then looking over my old code, it seemed to initialize correctly before. what the difference here was, i put the factory of the derived objects within a different object then the base class. what i used to do was declare a static function and static factory within the base class so that you could instantiate any of it's registered derived classes from the base class itself. When the factory is included within the base class instead, and instantiation is done through a static function, the initialization order of all the statics seems to be constently in order ( not sure if this is always true). It runs fine now after changing this.

so now, my answer, you can get operating system exceptions like this for trying to use references to objects that were never actually included anywhere in your project. I don't have a very good knowledge of compilers or linkers to tell you why it seemed to compile fine, despite this object never being included. If someone wants to extend my answer, please.

I use MSVC++ 2010 express if that pertains to this predicament.

Answer (score 2):

Here's *a* problem:

```
   std::map<std::string, base*(*)()>::iterator it = m_Map.find(s);
   return it->second();
```

if the call to `find` fails (i,e. it can't find 's' in the map), then it will return `m_Map.end()`.  Dereferencing that is a no-no.

Comment: this is true, which is why the if statement before checks whether it has an index 's', ensuring that find will not fail when called.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that this is due to the order of initialization of static variables. There is no way to control this order. So you are not guaranteed that your initialization:

```
Factory<A>::map_type Factory<A>::m_Map;
```

gets called before this initialization:

```
DEFINE_DERIVED(A, B, "B")
```

In this case the latter statement must be getting initialized first and so you map has not been allocated.

An alternative design pattern would control the initialization of the singleton factories. If you have an explicit Initialize function on each which creates the factory object then you can call this at the start of your main. E.g.

Factory.h

```
class Factory {
private:
    static Factory* instance_;
public:
    static Initialize(){instance_=new Factory;}
    Factory* instance(){return instance_;}
}
```

Factory.cpp

```
static Factory* Factory::instance_ = NULL;
```

If you have a lot of factories you will probably want a single initialize function that initializes them all, and you will have to remember to add in the new factories as you create them.